# Delphi FireDac (TFDConnection) connect to Sphinx service

Tags: delphi, sphinx, datasnap, firedac

It's possible connect Delphi with [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) with a TFDConnection? i have tried with this setting:

```
Port=9306
Server=127.0.0.1
DriverID=MySQL
```

but TFDConnection raise exception:

```
[FireDAC][Phys][MySQL]-1101. Unsupported MySQL version [203010000]. Supported are client and server from v 3.20 to v 6.2
```

Comment: If you have FireDAC source, then you can comment check for the MySQL version, which raises the exception. Then probably you will be able to connect. "Probably", because I have no idea how Sphinx is compatible with MySQL.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can get sphinx to report a fake version of mysql, something like 5.0.0 that might then work with your connection library

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-mysql-version-string